# Printing Multiple Copies in Shell Script

Tags: shell, printing

I have some issues with the printer where it is not printing correct number of copies when using lp command with -n option.

```
lp $file -n $numberofcopies
```

If I use command

```
lp file1.txt -n 2
```

. It prints 4 copies instead of 2.

Any ideas why printer might do that? I have Brother Label Printer installed on Ubuntu

Also in the mean time, how can I print multiple copies using a loop

Something..like below if I need 2 copies of file1.txt

```
lp file1.txt 
lp file1.txt
```

I was thinking about something like while loop. But now sure how?

Comment: Looks like a CUPS bug. Which version do you have installed? Do you get 9 copies if you ask for 3?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `seq 2` ; do
    lp $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

the option should be before argument (man lp)

```
lp -n 2 file
```

for the loop in bash

```
for((i=0;i<2;i++));do lp file;done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The lp still does print double copies after trying -n as you stated. The loop works just fine.. so it is working for now however, I am curious to find out why lp has issues with number of copies.